# Does using ActiveMQ in Master/Slave mode with JDBC preclude use of journaling?

Tags: activemq-classic

My group is looking to distribute our ActiveMQ queues across multiple brokers to achieve high availability. Of the three supported master-slave setups (pure, shared filesystem, JDBC) we are considering  shared file system and JDBC.

I am seeing conflicting statements within the ActiveMQ documentation. Can, or can not, JDBC master-slave setup use ActiveMQ's high-performance journal?

On [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html), ActiveMQ claims that

> it cannot use the high performance journal.

On [this page](http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html), ActiveMQ suggests that the two can, in fact, be used together:

> For long term persistence we recommend using JDBC coupled with our high performance journal.

Can anyone shed light on this apparent conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use journaling with JDBC master/slave because the journal is not replicated. Any messages in the journal of the master that have not yet been batch submitted to the jdbc store will be isolated till restart. ie: the journal is not visible to the slave.